# Use of definite article in thesis title

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Should "the" be used in this thesis title?

> "Reducing the Human Efforts in Data Analysis"

Should it be:

- "Reducing the Human Efforts in Data Analysis"

or:

- "Reducing Human Efforts in Data Analysis"

Comment: You should look up [headlinese](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-headlinese-1690921) - titles, like headlines, are often written without articles like *the*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could work with and without "the," but "effort" should not be plural.

The most natural and expected way to see this

> Reducing Human Effort in Data Analysis

or the alternative, slightly more awkward (in my opinion)

> Reducing the Human Effort in Data Analysis

============= Edit: additional clarification ===========

Your thesis is about reducing the **amount of effort** it takes to do something.  That amount is singular.

When we use the plural "efforts," we are talking about specific ongoing actions by various people.  For example

> The storm impeded cleanup efforts.

The plural of effort is not used to describe the abstract effort you are talking about in your work.  In other words, *you are not trying to stop people from doing data analysis, you are trying to reduce how much work it is for anyone to do data analysis.*

Comment: why does effort have to be plural? it can be either countable or uncountable, am I right?

Comment: I will expand my answer to clarify.